# Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, cell

Does anybody have the slightest idea on how I can achieve this type of effect on my table view cells?

[image]

or do you guys know a blog, Git, Repo that has nice TableViewCell make ups? thanks

Comment: You need to just take image of the background and use `UILabel` for text probably `autolayout` thru achieve your goal.

Comment: hmm i see @NimitParekh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your storyboard, make everything transparent and set those images as your background.
2. Then you can use '

> UIVisualEffectView | UIVisualEffectView with Blur class

' to set those blurs on your custom cells, make sure that your cell's background color is also in transparent mode.

or use

> CAGradientLayer Class

to set them up.

Answer (score 2):

If table's cell are static then you can create static custom cell in storyboard, Use Pin option in storyboard set left and right constraint for auto layout. Use background image and UILabel for creating for creating cell.

Answer (score 2):

check the below link, it will help you. 
use your own background image and font colur.
**Customize UITableView and UITableViewCell** 
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/